# Same page redirect using jQuery with different AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am new in jquery. I have created a user page which has different vendor's information button. When I click each button, respective information show in pop-up window.

But, i want to show the information on other page `"showInformation.jsp"` on click on `"View more" button` i.e. same page redirects every time, but information change on button click.

**JSP**

```
<div id="vendor-list">
    <c:forEach var="vendor" begin="0" end="11" items="${Vendor}">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="uploadImage/${vendor.logo}" alt="Logo1">
            <pre>${vendor.name}</pre>
            <button type="button" class="showInformation btn btn-primary" value="${vendor.userID}">View More</button>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#vendor-list").on('click',".showInformation",function() { 
         var user_id = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
           url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ViewInformation',
           type: 'GET',
           data: {user_id : user_id},
           success: function(data) {
           var vendor_Info = data;
           $('#singleVendor').html(vendor_Info).dialog({model:true}).dialog('open');
           }
         });
       });
     });
</script>
```

In the ajax call in url "ViewInformation" is servlet to get information from database.

Now, i want to rediect the same page, but when click any of button it show respective information.

Comment: hmmm, Your code looks fine ! What doesn't works ?

Comment: i want to page redirect on another page not to open pop-up window.

Comment: So you don't need ajax. You just need to submit a form with the vendor id and use a controller to redirect. From what I understand, this code in javascript is not yours, and you want to change its behaviour, right ?